# Can it be possible to have a CardLayout on a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

i'm actually working on a java software and i'm triyng to put a card layout on a card layout, there is my code (i've simplify it just to show you the problem) : 
 The first cardLayout and the button to navigate bewteen all cardLayout

```
 CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    JPanel PrimaryCard = new JPanel();
 [...] 
  PrimaryCard.setLayout(cardLayout);
    PrimaryCard.add(creer, "creer");
    PrimaryCard.add(modifier, "modifier");
    PrimaryCard.add(acceuil, "acceuil");
 [...]
 top.add(Acceuil);
    Acceuil.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         cardLayout.show(PrimaryCard, "acceuil");
        }
    });
```

The second CardLayout

```
CardLayout CreationCardLayout = new CardLayout();
    JPanel creationcard = new JPanel();
[...]
`creationcard.setLayout(CreationCardLayout);
    creationcard.add(CDevis, "CDevis");
    creationcard.add(CObjectifs, "CObjectifs");
    creationcard.add(CClient, "CClient");`
[...]
 creer.add(ButtonCDevis);
    ButtonCDevis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cardLayout.show(creationcard, "CDevis");
        }
    });
```

But when I click on the second button to go to the second CardLayou I Have this error code :

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(CardLayout.java:404)
at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:526)
at View.Jframe$7.actionPerformed(Jframe.java:172)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cardLayout.show(creationcard, "CDevis");
```

should be

```
CreationCardLayout.show(creationcard, "CDevis");
```